# How do you assign an action to multiple UITextFields using IB in xcode 4?

Tags: cocoa-touch, interface-builder

Is there a way to select all UITextFields and assign them to one Received Action?

Comment: Are you sure you mean all one received action or do you mean you want all text fields to fire the same action on some common target (like -userNameFieldsEdited: with the sender differentiated at runtime)?

Comment: Essentially I want all the text fields to fire the same action after the -Editing Did End event completes. Example would to validate the value of the text field. Hope this is clearer now and thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification, you can define an action in your controller and control-drag a connection from each field to the controller, connecting it to the same action. Since the sender (the field that fired the action) is included in the action, you can make your different choices based on the sender itself.

Read up on the [Target / Action mechanism](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html) here.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I will do it programmatically from now on.